# Creating a multi-channel RSS Feed

Tags: rss

I am trying to get a multi-channel RSS feed working. The feed seems to populate correctly if I use: `<link>{title_permalink="site/index"}</link>`, but as you can guess then each article just takes the subscriber to the index of the site.

I tried `<link>{title_permalink="{page_url}"}</link>`, but that broke the feed completely and it wouldn't populate.

How do I get it so that each entry in the feed links directly to the specific content item, regardless of channel?

My full XML code is here:

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="articles|blogs|news|reports"}
{preload_replace:master_channel_status="OPEN"}
{preload_replace:master_rss_uri="https://ntecheresearch.com/rss/content"}

{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}" status="{master_channel_status}"}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="https://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="https://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
    <title>{exp:xml_encode}n-tech Rearch RSS Feed{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
    <link>{channel_url}</link>
    <description></description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <pubDate>{gmt_date format="%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s %T"}</pubDate>
    <atom:link href="{master_rss_uri}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />   
{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="30" rdf="off" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|trackbacks" status="{master_channel_status}"}
    <item>
      <title>{exp:xml_encode protect_entities="yes"}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
      <link>{title_permalink="{page_url}"}</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">{title_permalink="site/index"}#id:{entry_id}#date:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i"}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{summary}]]></description>
      {categories}<category>{exp:xml_encode protect_entities="yes"}{category_name}{/exp:xml_encode}</category>
      {/categories}
      <pubDate>{gmt_entry_date format="%D, %d %M %Y %H:%i %T"}</pubDate>
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}
    </channel>
</rss>
{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<link>{title_permalink="{page_url}"}</link>` will never work because the `title_permalink` will be parsed before `page_url`. `page_url` [also just works on Page Module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#page-url).

It looks like the channels you're trying to add to the feed use different templates, which makes impossible to use the [`{url_title_path=""}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#id131). Is it?

If so, you have two options.

### first one

You can use [`{relative_url}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#relative-url), which returns the value of the [Channel URL on its settings](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#channel-url).

For each `<item>`, use:

```
<link>{relative_url}/{url_title}</link>
```

Or, if you're using **root** relative links on channels settings, which I prefer:

```
<link>{site_url}{relative_url}/{url_title}</link>
```

### second one

Conditionals! Check for the [`channel_short_name`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-short-name):

```
{if channel_short_name == "x"}
    <link>{title_permalink='x_template_group'} [...]
{if:else}
    <link>{title_permalink='y_template_group'} [...]
{/if}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  The root relative links example fixed it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @BrookeMartinChao, please, after test the answer, mark it as right to make easier to other having the same doubt. I'm glad I help you!